# AutoPairsDelete() noise with vim plugins

Tags: vimrc, vim8, plugin

I have been a `vim` user for years... I recently added a lot of plugins (see my [`~/.vimrc`](https://github.com/mpenning/vimrc/blob/2973cd6244ee4e65cbe2f2ce92446e7c3f355953/vimrc#L1)) and I keep hitting a problem where I type a word (in this case, a string called `cisco`) and `vim` a) sees an autocomplete possibility b) somehow inserts `AutoPairsDelete()` while I'm typing `cisco`.

[image: vim-unwanted-noise]

This is very annoying and counter-productive.

I'm running this version of `vim` on Debian Bullseye (Debian 11):

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Oct 01 2021 01:51:08)
Included patches: 1-2434
Extra patches: 8.2.3402, 8.2.3403, 8.2.3409, 8.2.3428
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: FWIW, Vim itself is not seeing any autocomplete possibility and it doesn't insert anything. Attributing those properties to Vim is a sadly common category error, often closely associated with adding lots of plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `let g:lsp_text_edit_enabled = 0` to my `~/.vimrc`.

```shell
" IMPORTANT lsp_text_edit_enabled = 0 to stop typos during LSP popup...
" see https://github.com/prabirshrestha/asyncomplete.vim/issues/156
let g:lsp_text_edit_enabled = 0
```

I haven't run into problems since I added that to my `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Maybe could you accept your own answer using the v green button next to the arrow voting button. You can accept your own answer two days after you post it. It all the question to rest :-)